# Kentico V9 CSS List Menu webpart for 2nd and 3rd level pages

Tags: kentico

I thought i had my left rail section nav working, untill i added some 3rd level pages. Here's a rough break down of the IA.

- sub 1.1
- sub 1.2
- sub 1.3

  - sub 1.3.1
  - sub 1.3.2
  - sub 1.3.3

My initial path was set to ../% and nav items for pages 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 works as expected. When i navigate to 1.3.1, i loose the parent node pages.

Here's a screen grab showing the full left nav.

[image: Left nav showing 2nd and 3rd level pages]

Here is how the nav looks when I'm on a 3rd level page (1.3.1):

[image: Left nav only showing 3rd level pages]

I came across this post, but it doesn't seem to work for me: http://devnet.kentico.com/questions/how-to-display-child-documents-if-they-exist-and-display-siblings-if-they-don%E2%80%99t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `/%` for a path. `../%` is a relative path.

See more details in [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Writing+page+path+expressions).

Comment: I currently have ../% for the path, but it doesn't seem to read nodes parent nodes, just child nodes.

Comment: remove dots before /%

Comment: That gives me the full nav, while i'm working with just a section sub nav.

Comment: ../% - takes all pages under the parent page of the current path, so once you navigate level down ../% results in another page.

Comment: Just specify your path like this: some_page/another_page/%, so it will show particular section in nav

Comment: As i'm in the Marketing section, this: /marketing/% work perfectly. But then i would have to create templates for each section, which i was hoping to avoid.

Comment: lol... Thanks Roman, i got it working, posted as an answer then saw your response. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I changed my path to this: /{0}/%

{0} is a wildcard for the first child node. I re-re-re-read of the Writing path expressions (https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/Writing+page+path+expressions), with some aid and trial and error helped.